# How to serialize this class?

Tags: c++, serialization

can somebody help me with serialization of this simple class in C++:

```
class State {
public:
    int count;
    Point point;
    double angle;
    Point* possible;
    int possibleSize;
    Line line;
    list<Point> route;

    State() {

    }

    ~State() {
        delete[] possible;
    }

};

// --- Structures

// Line structure (ax + by + c = 0)
struct Line {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

// Point structure
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

I can't use any 3rd party classes or libraries and I need to serialize this into byte array (or string). Can somebody write how? I just don't know how to start.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your class is buggy: it will invoke undefined behavior when copied or assigned because of `possible`, consider using a `std::vector<Point>` instead of a bare array.

Answer (score 6):

Serialization isn't magical.  All you need to do is write a function that saves every variable member of the class into an array in a predictable way and a match function to read such an array and set the correct members.

If this isn't for a class and you're allowed to use outside libraries, considering looking into the [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) library, especially if you'll be needing to serialize lots of different things.

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out how you're going to serialize all the `int`s and the `double`.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418319/serialize-double-and-float-with-c) has some hints for that.  Note that the `double` is much trickier than the `int`s.  And even though that question and its answers are in C, any C++ serialization would need to use the same central principles.

Two of your members look like variable-length lists.  A good way to serialize one of those is to serialize the number of elements (`possibleSize` or `route.size()`) followed by each element one at a time.